# Smooth scroll anchor links WITHOUT jQuery

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, anchor

Is it possible to use smooth scroll to anchor links but **without** `jQuery`? I am creating a new site and I don't want to use `jQuery`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Using the function from here: [JavaScript animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213259/javascript-animation) and modifying it to modify a property (not only a style's property), you can try something like this:

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7TAa2/1/

Just saying...

```js
function animate(elem, style, unit, from, to, time, prop) {
  if (!elem) {
    return;
  }
  var start = new Date().getTime(),
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      var step = Math.min(1, (new Date().getTime() - start) / time);
      if (prop) {
        elem[style] = (from + step * (to - from)) + unit;
      } else {
        elem.style[style] = (from + step * (to - from)) + unit;
      }
      if (step === 1) {
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, 25);
  if (prop) {
    elem[style] = from + unit;
  } else {
    elem.style[style] = from + unit;
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  var target = document.getElementById("div5");
  animate(document.scrollingElement || document.documentElement, "scrollTop", "", 0, target.offsetTop, 2000, true);
};
```

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">asdf1</div>
<div id="div2">asdf2</div>
<div id="div3">asdf3</div>
<div id="div4">asdf4</div>
<div id="div5">asdf5</div>
<div id="div6">asdf6</div>
<div id="div7">asdf7</div>
<div id="div8">asdf8</div>
<div id="div9">asdf9</div>
<div id="div10">asdf10</div>
<div id="div10">asdf11</div>
<div id="div10">asdf12</div>
<div id="div10">asdf13</div>
<div id="div10">asdf14</div>
<div id="div10">asdf15</div>
<div id="div10">asdf16</div>
<div id="div10">asdf17</div>
<div id="div10">asdf18</div>
<div id="div10">asdf19</div>
<div id="div10">asdf20</div>
```

Comment: To people trying that out : that's great script but don't expect any easing or nice tween. This is kind of a raw steppy animation.

Comment: Similar attempts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063380/javascript-smooth-scroll-without-the-use-of-jquery & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917921/cross-browser-javascript-not-jquery-scroll-to-top-animation

Comment: @mtness It works fine in Firefox (the code, maybe not the demo). You need to update what element you're animating, because Firefox apparently doesn't like changing the `scrollTop` of `document.body` (took a quick debug and Google search to figure this out). Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/zpu16nen/ (I'll update this post)

Answer (score 63):

Extending this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8918062/3851798

After defining your function of scrollTo, you can pass the element you want to scrollTo in the function.

```
function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
    if (duration <= 0) return;
    var difference = to - element.scrollTop;
    var perTick = difference / duration * 10;

    setTimeout(function() {
        element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
        if (element.scrollTop === to) return;
        scrollTo(element, to, duration - 10);
    }, 10);
}
```

If you have a div with an id="footer"

```
<div id="footer" class="categories">…</div>
```

In the script that you run to scroll you can run this,

```
elmnt = document.getElementById("footer");
scrollTo(document.body, elmnt.offsetTop, 600);
```

And there you have it. Smooth scrolling without jQuery. You can actually play around with that code on your browser's console and fine tune it to your liking.

Comment: I had to pass `document.documentElement` into the function instead of `document.body` to make it work

Comment: document.body for edge, document.documentElement for chrome.

Comment: edge browser supports `document.documentElement` since version 12. MDN ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement#browser_compatibility. 
caniuse ref: https://caniuse.com/?search=documentElement

Answer (score 53):

Actually, there is more lightweight and simple way to do that:
https://codepen.io/ugg0t/pen/mqBBBY

```js
function scrollTo(element) {
  window.scroll({
    behavior: 'smooth',
    left: 0,
    top: element.offsetTop
  });
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollTo(document.getElementById("8"));
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}

div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: white;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
<div id="5"></div>
<div id="6"></div>
<div id="7"></div>
<div id="8"></div>
<div id="9"></div>
<div id="10"></div>
<button id="button">Button</button>
```

Comment: Only issue is that instead of ``element.offsetTop`` you should use ``element.getBoundingClientRect().top +  window.scrollY``

Comment: @zdolny It now works on native Edge, but for IE you will need a polyfill - https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll

Comment: @ekfuhrmann [I don't care about IE](https://element5digital.com/why-wont-support-internet-explorer-and-neither-should-you/) but does it work in Safari? Or should I not care about Safari too?

Comment: This is the same as simply adding `scroll-behavior: smooth`, which works well in most current browsers, but Safari has not adopted.

Comment: @Orun Now Safari supports it.

Answer (score 14):

This is a pretty old question, but it's important to say that nowadays smooth scrolling is supported in CSS, so there's no need for any scripts:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

As noted by [@Andiih](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107565/andiih), as of late 2022 there is [full browser support](https://caniuse.com/css-scroll-behavior) for this.

Comment: As of mid 2022 support for scroll-behaviour is now pretty solid ( https://caniuse.com/css-scroll-behavior )

Comment: My hero...  I added some text so I can comment.

Comment: Worked well for a project I'm working on just now.

Answer (score 8):

Use this:

```
let element = document.getElementById("box");

element.scrollIntoView();
element.scrollIntoView(false);
element.scrollIntoView({block: "end"});
element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "instant", block: "end", inline: "nearest"});
```

**DEMO**: https://jsfiddle.net/anderpo/x8ucc5ak/1/

Comment: try to add some explanations

Comment: Explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Very interesting solution (+1) but not being supported in IE stinks at the moment!

Comment: More or less the same as `scroll-behavior: smooth`, which isn't supported in Safari (or IE, but more importantly modern Safari).

Answer (score 7):

Vanilla js variant using `requestAnimationFrame` with easings and all browsers supported:

```javascript
const requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

function scrollTo(to) {
    const start = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset
    const time = Date.now()
    const duration = Math.abs(start - to) / 3;

    (function step() {
        var dx = Math.min(1, (Date.now() - time) / duration)
        var pos = start + (to - start) * easeOutQuart(dx)

        window.scrollTo(0, pos)

        if (dx < 1) {
            requestAnimationFrame(step)
        }
    })()
}
```

Any [easing](https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294) supported!

Comment: Very nice answer.. Tested  on safari, chrome.

Comment: I find this the best answer. Short, performant, customisable and works wonders.  `requestAnimationFrame()` suits better for scrolling than `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 4):

CSS3 transitions with a `:target` selector can give a nice result without any JS hacking. I was just contemplating whether to imlement this but without Jquery it does get a bit messy. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631417/css-pure-css-scroll-animation) for details.

Comment: Why not include the most important bit? `html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }` - so simple and works a treat, if you're okay to eschew IE support

Comment: IE support is one thing, but it doesn't work in modern Safari either.

Answer (score 4):

Smooth Scroll behavior with polyfill...

Example:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector(this.getAttribute("href")).scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
});
```

Repository: https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll

Comment: You can't listen click event with querySelectorAll, it returns an array.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code here:

```
window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

#### March 2022

I know this is an old question but wanted to put forward an answer that has simpler ways of doing it in modern days. As of today, almost all the major browsers are compatible with `scroll-behavior` including Safari with its latest release. Still, you might want to employ fallback methods or just use the javascript approach described in method 2 for compatibility in older browsers.

### Method 1: HTML and CSS

You can just do this with

```html
<a href="#target" id="scroll-trigger">Click</a>
.
.
.
<h2 id="target">Target</h2>
```

and CSS

```css
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth
}
```

### Method 2: JavaScript

Or if you have a unique case that needs javascript, go on elaborate with this method.

```js
const scrollTrigger = document.getElementById('scroll-trigger');
const target = document.getElementById('target');

scrollTrigger.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    window.scroll({
        top: target.offsetTop,
        left:0,
        behavior: 'smooth' });
}, false)
```

Comment: You can use `Element.scrollIntoView` with just `behavior: "smooth"` instead of `window.scroll` (which requires `top` and `left` as well).

Comment: This is great! Note that the CSS solution won't work in IE. https://caniuse.com/css-scroll-behavior

Answer (score 3):

My favorite scroll-to library currently is [Zenscroll](https://zengabor.github.io/zenscroll/) because of the [wide range of features](https://zengabor.github.io/zenscroll/#howtouse) and small size (currently only 3.17kb).

In the future it may make more sense to use the native [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility) functionality, but since it'd have to be polyfilled in most production sites today due to the lack of IE support, I recommend using Zenscroll instead in all cases.

Comment: amem! This is only library which is currently working as I expected. Thanks!

Comment: @zach-sauchier Would you still recommend to use this library today or did you move on to a native solution?

Comment: There's still no native solution. There are a lot of alternatives these days, like GSAP's ScrollToPlugin

Answer (score 1):

It's upgraded version from @Ian

```
// Animated scroll with pure JS
// duration constant in ms
const animationDuration = 600;
// scrollable layout
const layout = document.querySelector('main');
const fps = 12;  // in ms per scroll step, less value - smoother animation
function scrollAnimate(elem, style, unit, from, to, time, prop) {
    if (!elem) {
        return;
    }
    var start = new Date().getTime(),
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            var step = Math.min(1, (new Date().getTime() - start) / time);
            var value =  (from + step * (to - from)) + unit;
            if (prop) {
                elem[style] = value;
            } else {
                elem.style[style] = value;
            }
            if (step === 1) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, fps);
    if (prop) {
        elem[style] = from + unit;
    } else {
        elem.style[style] = from + unit;
    }
}

function scrollTo(hash) {
    const target = document.getElementById(hash);
    const from = window.location.hash.substring(1) || 'start';
    const offsetFrom = document.getElementById(from).offsetTop;
    const offsetTo = target.offsetTop;
    scrollAnimate(layout,
        "scrollTop", "", offsetFrom, offsetTo, animationDuration, true);
    setTimeout(function () {
      window.location.hash = hash;
    }, animationDuration+25)
};

// add scroll when click on menu items 
var menu_items = document.querySelectorAll('a.mdl-navigation__link');
menu_items.forEach(function (elem) {
    elem.addEventListener("click",
        function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            scrollTo(elem.getAttribute('href').substring(1));
        });
});

// scroll when open link with anchor 
window.onload = function () {
    if (window.location.hash) {
        var target = document.getElementById(window.location.hash.substring(1));
        scrollAnimate(layout, "scrollTop", "", 0, target.offsetTop, animationDuration, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone in 2019, 
first, you add an event listener

```
  document.getElementById('id').addEventListener('click', () => scrollTo())
```

then you target the element and go smoothly to it

```
function scrollTo() {
    let target = document.getElementById('target');
    target.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth", 
        block: "end", 
        inline: "nearest"
    })
}
```

Comment: NOTE: This example has very limited support as is. Arrow functions won't work in any version of IE, Opera Mini, Blackberry Browser, IE Mobile and QQ Browser without using a transpiler such as Babel caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions and the behaviour 'smooth' also has pretty significant lack of support as of 2019 https://caniuse.com/#search=scrollIntoView

Answer (score 1):

Based on [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScrollToOptions/behavior) for scroll options we can use the following code:

```
element.scrollTo({
  top: 100,
  left: 100,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

In fact, the `behavior` key can accept `smooth` and `auto` variables. first for smooth motion and second for a single jump.
‍‍

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution in **pure JavaScript**. It takes advantage of CSS property **scroll-behavior: smooth**

```
function scroll_to(id) {       
    document.documentElement.style.scrollBehavior = 'smooth'
    element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', id)
    element.click();
}
```

**Usage**:

Say we have 10 divs:

```
<div id='df7ds89' class='my_div'>ONE</div>
<div id='sdofo8f' class='my_div'>TWO</div>
<div id='34kj434' class='my_div'>THREE</div>
<div id='gbgfh98' class='my_div'>FOUR</div>
<div id='df89sdd' class='my_div'>FIVE</div>
<div id='34l3j3r' class='my_div'>SIX</div>
<div id='56j5453' class='my_div'>SEVEN</div>
<div id='75j6h4r' class='my_div'>EIGHT</div>
<div id='657kh54' class='my_div'>NINE</div>
<div id='43kjhjh' class='my_div'>TEN</div>
```

We can **scroll to the ID of choice**:

```
scroll_to('#657kh54')
```

You simply **call this function on your click event** (e.g. click button then scroll to div #9).

**Result**:

[image]

Of course it looks much smoother in real life.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/CyberneticSean/jxcpo34b/7/)

Unfortunately, IE and Safari don't support scrollBehavior = 'smooth' as of **2019**

[image]
[MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

For a more comprehensive list of methods for smooth scrolling, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51689657/9513184).

---

To scroll to a certain position in an exact amount of time, [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) can be put to use, calculating the appropriate current position each time. [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) can be used to a similar effect when `requestAnimationFrame` is not supported.

```js
/*
   @param pos: the y-position to scroll to (in pixels)
   @param time: the exact amount of time the scrolling will take (in milliseconds)
*/
function scrollToSmoothly(pos, time) {
    var currentPos = window.pageYOffset;
    var start = null;
    if(time == null) time = 500;
    pos = +pos, time = +time;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function step(currentTime) {
        start = !start ? currentTime : start;
        var progress = currentTime - start;
        if (currentPos < pos) {
            window.scrollTo(0, ((pos - currentPos) * progress / time) + currentPos);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, currentPos - ((currentPos - pos) * progress / time));
        }
        if (progress < time) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, pos);
        }
    });
}
```

Demo:

```js
function scrollToSmoothly(pos, time) {
    var currentPos = window.pageYOffset;
    var start = null;
    if(time == null) time = 500;
    pos = +pos, time = +time;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function step(currentTime) {
        start = !start ? currentTime : start;
        var progress = currentTime - start;
        if (currentPos < pos) {
            window.scrollTo(0, ((pos - currentPos) * progress / time) + currentPos);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, currentPos - ((currentPos - pos) * progress / time));
        }
        if (progress < time) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, pos);
        }
    });
}

document.getElementById("toElement").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var elem = document.querySelector("div");
  scrollToSmoothly(elem.offsetTop);
});
document.getElementById("toTop").addEventListener('click', function(e){
  scrollToSmoothly(0, 700);
});
```

```html
<button id="toElement">Scroll To Element</button>
<div style="margin: 1000px 0px; text-align: center;">Div element
  <button id="toTop">Scroll back to top</button>
</div>
```

For more complex cases, the [SmoothScroll.js library](https://github.com/LieutenantPeacock/SmoothScroll) can be used, which handles smooth scrolling both vertically and horizontally, scrolling inside other container elements, different easing behaviors, scrolling relatively from the current position, and more.

```js
document.getElementById("toElement").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  smoothScroll({toElement: document.querySelector('div'), duration: 500});
});
document.getElementById("toTop").addEventListener('click', function(e){
  smoothScroll({yPos: 0, duration: 700});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/LieutenantPeacock/SmoothScroll@1.2.0/src/smoothscroll.min.js" integrity="sha384-UdJHYJK9eDBy7vML0TvJGlCpvrJhCuOPGTc7tHbA+jHEgCgjWpPbmMvmd/2bzdXU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button id="toElement">Scroll To Element</button>
<div style="margin: 1000px 0px; text-align: center;">Div element
  <button id="toTop">Scroll back to top</button>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can pass an options object to [`window.scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/scroll) which scrolls to a specific x and y position and [`window.scrollBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/scrollBy) which scrolls a certain amount from the current position:

```
// Scroll to specific values
// scrollTo is the same
window.scroll({
  top: 2500, 
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});

// Scroll certain amounts from current position 
window.scrollBy({ 
  top: 100, // could be negative value
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});
```

Demo:

```html
<button onClick="scrollToDiv()">Scroll To Element</button>
<div style="margin: 500px 0px;">Div</div>
<script>
function scrollToDiv(){
var elem = document.querySelector("div");
window.scroll({
      top: elem.offsetTop, 
      left: 0, 
      behavior: 'smooth' 
});
}
</script>
```

Modern browsers support the [`scroll-behavior` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior), which can be used to make scrolling in the document smooth (without the need for JavaScript).  Anchor tags can be used for this by giving the anchor tag a `href` of `#` plus the `id` of the element to scroll to). You can also set the `scroll-behavior` property for a specific container like a `div` to make its contents scroll smoothly.

```css
html, body{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<a href="#elem">Scroll To Element</a>
<div id="elem" style="margin: 500px 0px;">Div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without **jQuery**

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('header nav ul a')

for (const link of links) {
  link.onclick = function clickHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const href = this.getAttribute('href')
    document.querySelector(href).scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
  }
}
```

```css
  body {
    background-color: black;
    height:7000px
  }

  header {
    margin-top: 1.3rem;
    margin-bottom: 25rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  nav ul {
    display: flex;
  }

  nav ul li {
    all: unset;
    margin: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  nav ul li a {
    all: unset;
    font: bold 1.8rem robto;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-top: 3rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
  }

  #team,
  #contact,
  #about {
    background-color: #e2df0d;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: black;
    font: bold 4rem roboto;
    letter-spacing: 6.2px;
    margin-top: 70rem;

  }
```

```html
<header>
  <!-- NavBar -->
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<!-- ----------- Team ----------------------- -->
<div id="team">
  <h2>Team</h2>
</div>

<!-- ----------- Contact ----------------------- -->
<div id="contact">
  <h2>Contact</h2>
</div>

<!-- ----------- About ----------------------- -->
<div id="about">
  <h2>About</h2>
</div>
```

Or with just **CSS**, but it's not supported in all browsers yet

`html {scroll-behavior: smooth}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set all of your deep links `#` to scroll smoothly you can do this:

```
const allLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]')
allLinks.forEach(link => {

  const 
    targetSelector = link.getAttribute('href'),
    target = document.querySelector(targetSelector)

  if (target) {
    link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault()

    const top = target.offsetTop // consider decreasing your main nav's height from this number

    window.scroll({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      left: 0,
      top: top
    });

  })
}
})
```

An example code to consider also your main nav's height (this code goes where `top` const is declared):

```
const 
  mainHeader = document.querySelector('header#masthead'), //change to your correct main nav selector
  mainHeaderHeight = mainHeader.offsetHeight,
  // now calculate top like this:
  top = target.offsetTop - mainHeaderHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the most elegant and concise solution.**

> Links:

```
<a href="#elementIDtoScrollTo"></a>
```

> CSS:

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Remember to add a unique `id="elementIDtoScrollTo"` to each HTML element.