# Fullscreen sections changing by translateX

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

I would gain effect like: fullscreen sections (left to right) which I can change by translateX.

My first try unfortunately move whole wrapper instead of its content:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WPzBYm

```js
const sectionsWrapper = document.getElementById("sections-wrapper");

sectionsWrapper.style.transform = "translateX(-100px)";
```

```css
html, body {
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;      
}
.section {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.s1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.s2 {
  background-color: coral;
}
.s3 {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div id="sections-wrapper" class="wrapper">
  <div class="section s1">elo1</div>
  <div class="section s2">elo2</div>
  <div class="section s3">elo3</div>
</div>
```

Target effect:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is your goal, but if you want scroll your sections try this code:

The original code for animate (in vanilla javascript) is here: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733076/smooth-scroll-anchor-links-without-jquery)

```js
//const sectionsWrapper = document.getElementById("sections-wrapper");

//sectionsWrapper.style.transform = "translateX(-100px)";



function animate(elem, style, unit, from, to, time, prop) {
    if (!elem) {
        return;
    }
    var start = new Date().getTime(),
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            var step = Math.min(1, (new Date().getTime() - start) / time);
            if (prop) {
                elem[style] = (from + step * (to - from))+unit;
            } else {
                elem.style[style] = (from + step * (to - from))+unit;
            }
            if (step === 1) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, 25);
    if (prop) {
          elem[style] = from+unit;
    } else {
          elem.style[style] = from+unit;
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("sections-wrapper");
    var s2 = document.getElementById("s2");
    animate(wrapper, "scrollLeft", "", 0, s2.offsetLeft, 1000, true);
};
```

```css
html, body{
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
/*   overflow: hidden; */
  
}

.section{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.s1{
  background-color: yellow;
}

.s2{
  background-color: coral;
}

.s3{
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div id="sections-wrapper" class="wrapper">
  <div id="s1" class="section s1">elo1</div>
  <div id="s2" class="section s2">elo2</div>
  <div id="s3" class="section s3">elo3</div>
</div>
```

*Hope this help you.*

Comment: I add target effect in oryginal question.

Comment: On StackOverflow we can't work for you, you have the example in my answer and you can do all the rest alone, but because I have time to lost and because it's funny check this: https://jsfiddle.net/hk3j09ec/3/. Good Luck :)

Comment: Don't worry, its not commercial. I made similar code alone, before I asked, but thanks for indicate scrollLeft property.

Answer (score 0):

CHECK THIS.

```js
sectionsWrapper.style.transform = "translateY(200px)";
```

```js
const sectionsWrapper = document.getElementById("sections-wrapper");

sectionsWrapper.style.transform = "translateY(200px)";
```

Comment: I used it before to vertical sections, but now I'm asking about HTML layout to implement horizontal move.