# How to control scroll time without jquery when smooth scrolling to element?

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm trying to scroll to element smoothly,but can't find a way to control the scroll time without jquery.

I found two ways to scroll to element smoothly:

1. document.getElementById(targetElementId).scrollIntoView({behavior:'smooth'})

2.$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(selector).offset().top},1000)

The second way uses jquery and easy to control scroll time.

But I wonder if there a way in native javascript to control the scroll time.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this function :

[Smooth scroll anchor links WITHOUT jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733076/smooth-scroll-anchor-links-without-jquery)

Scroll time is used as parameter.

Comment: Thank you.And wow it's so much work to do it with pure javascript.