# Javascript prevent orientationchange eventhandler from being able to execute multiple times simultaneously

Tags: javascript, event-handling, global-variables, orientation-changes, removeeventlistener

I'm currently experiencing a problem in Javascript when I try to prevent an eventhandler from being called multiple times simultaneously. I know that Javascript is single threaded and my question therefore seems strange.

Here is the code that is loaded inside the head of my html file via `<script src="main.js"></script>`:

```
function showAlert ( ) {
  window.removeEventListener ( 'orientationchange' , showAlert );
  alert ( 'alert' );
  // code execution doesn't seem to stop here while the alert is open
  window.addEventListener ( 'orientationchange' , showAlert );
}

function onLoad ( ) {
  document.removeEventListener ( 'DOMContentLoaded' , onLoad );
  window.addEventListener ( 'orientationchange' , showAlert );
}

document.addEventListener ( 'DOMContentLoaded' , onLoad );
```

When I turn my phone the alert is shown. Unfortunately, when I don't close the alert and turn my phone again, a second alert is shown. This should not happen because I already removed the eventlistener before showing the first alert.

I've also tried to prevent this behavior via a global variable, but it didn't work either:

```
var alertIsShown = false;

function showAlert ( ) {
  if ( alertIsShown == false ) {
    alertIsShown = true;
    alert ( 'alert' );
    // code execution doesn't stop here
    alertIsShown = false;
  }
  //alertIsShown = false; // doesn't matter if I put the alert here
}

function onLoad ( ) {
  document.removeEventListener ( 'DOMContentLoaded' , onLoad );
  window.addEventListener ( 'orientationchange' , showAlert );
}

document.addEventListener ( 'DOMContentLoaded' , onLoad );
```

I've also checked if the DOMContentLoaded event was somehow triggered multiple times, but it wasn't the case.

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609994/javascript-prevent-function-from-executing-multiple-times) seems to be similiar, but I get an alert no matter how long I wait before turning my phone.

Is there any Javascript Guru out there that can help me out?

**Update 01:** I found out that despite what the majority on the internet says, a pause of the code execution while an alert message is shown is defined as optional in the official [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-alert).
Unfortunately, switching to confirm didn't solve my problem either. When the phone is rotate while the  message box is showing, another message box is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a JS Guru and I didn't know why you asked, but your first approach is almost correct. Remove last line of `showAlert` where you add new event listener.
this solution works fine, tested on iphone 10

```
function test() {
    window.removeEventListener('orientationchange', test);
    alert('orientation change')
}

window.addEventListener('orientationchange', test);
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. Maybe I should have been more precise with my wording. In fact I do want the event to be triggered again. Just not while the alert is shown. That's why I readded the eventlistener at the end of the function.