# Css3 Transition will not work

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to make a page slide out from outside of the screen by using a css3 transition. I'm able to get the page on the screen but I cannot get it to slide out when I click on the respective button(s).

The transition in my css file:

```
#about {
  background: #262626;
  opacity: 0.75;
  filter: alpha(opacity=75);
  width: 100%;
  height: 364px;
  position: -99999px left;
}

#about:target {
  position: +99999px left;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
}
```

The button(s) in my html file: (Just working on the About me page at the moment)

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="hidden">
      <a href="#page-top"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-scroll">
      <a href="#portfolio">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-scroll">
      <a href="#about">About me</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-scroll">
      <a href="#media">Media</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some of your code in the question. Also, consider opening a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) with the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Please click on the link it will show you everything i'm working with.

Comment: We can't work with picture.

Comment: If you want people to spend time helping you. Please take time to ask a good question, so it will be easier to give you a good and helpful answer.

Comment: I doesn't seem fixed to me. You really should add the code as text in the question. I maybe add some code concerning the transition.

Comment: Sorry about that I'm pretty new around here. I changed it once more, this should help hopefully.

Comment: Yes I can see that you are new, don't worry, with time you will understand what is a good question and how to get a good and helpful answer quickly. Right now, I don't think it can be achieved with only CSS. Still, i'm not 100% certain to understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020582/scrolling-to-an-anchor-using-transition-css3)? It seems to be the same question, plus, it has a [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/YYPKM/3/).

And it works with only CSS with `transform` and `transition`.

Comment: Thank you, for all your help Cohars!