# How to add a smooth transition effect

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

Anyone know how I can add a smooth transition effect to this?
[image]

I tried this in a JS file, but it kept showing a white outline around each div:

```js
$(function () {
    menu = $('nav ul');

    $('#toggle-btn').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.slideToggle();
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        var w = $(this).width();
        if (w > 580 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });

    $('nav li').on('click', function (e) {
        var w = $(window).width();
        if (w < 580) {
            menu.slideToggle();
        }
    });
    $('.open-menu').height($(window).height());
});

// smooth scrolling

$('a[href*="#"]')
    .not('[href="#"]')
    .not('[href="#0"]')
    .click(function (event) {
        if (
            location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') &&
            location.hostname == this.hostname
        ) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000, function () {
                    var $target = $(target);
                    $target.focus();
                    if ($target.is(":focus")) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        $target.attr('tabindex', '-1');
                        $target.focus();
                    };
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

I tried a few other methods but they didn't work. Is there a way to do this with CSS? Or can it only be done using JS?

Comment: hello. insert your html and css pls

Comment: Can you add a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question? If we have a working example to work on, it makes it easier for us to help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrolling to an Anchor using Transition/CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020582/scrolling-to-an-anchor-using-transition-css3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a smooth scroll effect with css:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```