# Scrolling to an anchor with pure CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to scroll from a bootstrap nav links to matching anchors on my page using only CSS (no jquery). This answer from @jesus-bejarano ([CSS: pure CSS scroll animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631417/css-pure-css-scroll-animation)) with matching jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/YYPKM/3/) seems to be a great solution but I can't seem to get it working. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is a link to a bootply with what I've got: http://www.bootply.com/15Ib1TGYeV

Appreciate the help.

My HTML:

```
<a id="suds"></a>
<a id="apoth"></a>
<a id="merch"></a>
<div class="container-fluid container-fullwidth" id="" style="">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <!-- <div class="container-fluid"> -->
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></span>

                    <!-- <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> -->

                </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></span></a>

            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#suds" class="">Suds</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#apoth" class="">Apothecary and Men's Grooming</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#merch" class="">Gifts and Merchandise</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        <!-- </div> -->
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <section class="row no-gutter main">
      <article class="merch-cat" id="suds">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <a href="#" class=""><img src="http://placehold.it/600X400" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <a href="#" class=""><img src="http://placehold.it/600X400" class="img-responsive"></a>   
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <a href="#" class=""><img src="http://placehold.it/600X400" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <a href="#" class=""><img src="http://placehold.it/600X400" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <a href="#" class=""><img src="http://placehold.it/600X400" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <a href="#" class=""><img src="http://placehold.it/600X400" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
      </article>
      <article class="merch-cat" id="apoth">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <a href="#" class=""><img src="http://placehold.it/600X400" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <a href="#" class=""><img src="http://placehold.it/600X400" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <a href="#" class=""><img src="http://placehold.it/600X400" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
      </article>
      <article class="merch-cat" id="merch">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <a href="#" class=""><img src="http://placehold.it/600X400" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <a href="#" class=""><img src="http://placehold.it/600X400" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <a href="#" class=""><img src="http://placehold.it/600X400" class="img-responsive"></a>
            </div>
      </article>
     </section>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
/* add a little bottom space under the images */
body { 
    padding-top: 0px;
}


.thumbnail {
    margin-bottom:0;
}

.row.no-gutter {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:first-child),
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.container-fullwidth {
        width: 100%;
  }

/* make nav always collapsed */

@media (max-width: 2000px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}

/* nav opacity */

    nav {
        opacity: 0.5
  }

/* scrolling */
a[ id= "suds" ]:target ~ #main article.merch-cat {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( 0px);
    transform: translateY( 0px );
}

a[ id= "apoth" ]:target ~ #main article.merch-cat {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -500px );
    transform: translateY( -500px );
}
a[ id= "merch" ]:target ~ #main article.merch-cat {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -1000px );
    transform: translateY( -1000px );
}
```

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Comment: Sure @daniel. Will do in the future. Any thoughts on how to get this working? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if this will help you any.. but i used this on a profile of mine to scroll certain items

```
@-webkit-keyframes buzz-out {
  10% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    transform:translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  }

  20% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    transform:translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  }

  30% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    transform:translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    transform:translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
    transform:translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
  }

  60% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
    transform:translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }

  70% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
    transform:translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
    transform:translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }

  90% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(1px) rotate(0);
    transform:translateX(1px) rotate(0);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-1px) rotate(0);
    transform:translateX(-1px) rotate(0);
  }
}

@keyframes buzz-out {
  10% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    -ms-transform:translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    transform:translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  }

  20% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    -ms-transform:translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    transform:translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  }

  30% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    -ms-transform:translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    transform:translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    -ms-transform:translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    transform:translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
    -ms-transform:translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
    transform:translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
  }

  60% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
    -ms-transform:translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
    transform:translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }

  70% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
    -ms-transform:translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
    transform:translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
    -ms-transform:translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
    transform:translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }

  90% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(1px) rotate(0);
    -ms-transform:translateX(1px) rotate(0);
    transform:translateX(1px) rotate(0);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-1px) rotate(0);
    -ms-transform:translateX(-1px) rotate(0);
    transform:translateX(-1px) rotate(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a complete working example using these keyframes?

Comment: Thanks @joshua but I'm not quite sure how this helps.

Comment: @misterManSam 
here is the entire code for it.. prob wont help you on what your trying to do but this is how its set up to work for needed

Answer (score 0):

@misterManSam

```
@charset "UTF-8";

html {
  background:url(https://googledrive.com/host/0B6ETuSl1xvFHZVY1TGlFb0dlLVE/back.png) no-repeat center 0,#000 url(https://googledrive.com/host/t0B6ETuSl1xvFHZVY1TGlFb0dlLVE/back.gif) left top;
}

img {
  -webkit-border-radius:8px;
  -moz-border-radius:8px;
  border-radius:8px;
}

.mnmembers {
  margin:50px -20px;
}

body {
  font-family:Trebuchet MS,Arial,Helvetica;
  text-align:center;
}

body,td {
  color:#fff;
  font-size:12px;
}

.friends_value img {
  border:0;
}

td .clock {
  font-size:23px;
}

.container_padding {
  height:100%;
}

.gallery_image img {
  margin:5px;
}

.gallery_image {
  border:0;
}

.container_transparency {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.container {
  height:100%;
  background-color:transparent;
}

.container .heading {
  color:#FF00CC;
  text-shadow:2px 2px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:Cabin Sketch,sans-serif;
  font-size:20px;
}

.about_me .value {
  color:#FF00CC;
  font-size:15px;
}

.container table {
  margin:15px;
}

.container table table {
  border:0;
  background:none;
}

#framepo {
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 150px;
}

#myvid {
  margin:1000px 10px 0;
}

#stuff {
  width:1194px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  margin:1000px 0 0;
  text-align:center;
}

.container table tr td.key {
  background:#4a4057;
  border-bottom:1px solid #443b50;
  border-right:1px solid #383143;
}

.container table tr td.key,.container table tr td.friends_key {
  padding:8px 8px 8px 20px;
}

.container table tr td.status_key,.container table tr td.blurb_key {
  padding:3px 3px 3px 50px;
}

.wall_options textarea {
  border:1px solid #0061aa;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  margin-top:20px 0 -20px 0;
}

a,a:link,a:active,a:visited,a:hover {
  color:#fff;
}

.bottom_footer_wrapper {
  bordet-top:#352f40 5px solid;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  z-index:9999;
}

#videocontainer {
  z-index:1;
}

.bottom_footer_wrapper .bottom_footer {
  background-color:#fff;
  border-top:3px solid #fb15d3;
  height:80px;
  text-align:center;
}

.container a.desc-img img {
  -moz-transform:rotate(-2deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-2deg);
}

div.gallery_content:hover {
  bottom:0;
}

div.gallery_content .gallery_image {
  font-size:12px;
  width:175px;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0!important;
}

input[name='strip_links'] {
  margin-bottom:170px;
}

input[type='submit'] {
  background:none;
  display:block;
  margin-top:25px;
  letter-spacing:-1px;
  border-width:1px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#ccc #444 #111;
  border-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7) rgba(0,0,0,0.5) rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  font:bold 21px1em Arial;
  color:white;
  padding:.48em 2em;
  cursor:pointer;
  text-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.45) 0 -1px 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0 0 3px;
  -moz-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0 0 3px;
  box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0 0 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius:7px;
  -moz-border-radius:7px;
  border-radius:7px;
  background:transparent -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(rgba(255,255,255,0.6)),color-stop(0.5,rgba(255,255,255,0.15)),color-stop(0.5,rgba(255,255,255,0.01)),to(transparent));
  background:transparent -moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(255,255,255,0.6),rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0.01) 50%,transparent);
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorstr='#80FFFFFF',EndColorstr='#00FFFFFF');
  -webkit-background-clip:padding-box;
}

input[type='submit']:hover {
  border-top-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.65);
  background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(rgba(220,220,220,0.6)),color-stop(0.5,rgba(100,100,100,0.2)),color-stop(0.5,rgba(0,0,0,0.21)),to(rgba(0,0,0,0.20)));
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(220,220,220,0.6),rgba(100,100,100,0.2) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0.21) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0.20));
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#99dcdcdc',EndColorStr='#33000000');
  -webkit-background-clip:padding-box;
}

textarea {
  color:#666;
  font-size:14px;
  -moz-border-radius:8px;
  -webkit-border-radius:8px;
  padding:0 10px;
  margin:15px 0;
  border:#999 1px solid;
  font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode','Lucida Grande',sans-serif;
  transition:all .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition:all .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all .25s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(81,203,238,0);
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(81,203,238,0);
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(81,203,238,0);
}

textarea#styleid:focus {
  color:#000;
  outline:none;
  border:#35a5e5 1px solid;
  font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode','Lucida Grande',sans-serif;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(81,203,238,1);
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(81,203,238,1);
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(81,203,238,1);
}

.container .interests_body a img,.container img.thumbnail {
  -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
}

#schedule table {
  margin-top:10px;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid #81729a;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
  border-top-left-radius:5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  box-shadow:0 1px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}

#schedule tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom:none!important;
}

#schedule tr:first-child td {
  border-top:none!important;
}

#schedule td:last-child {
  border-right:none!important;
}

#schedule td {
  border-top:2px solid #81729a;
  border-bottom:1px solid #81729a;
  border-right:1px solid #81729a;
  padding:13px 8px;
}

#profile {
  width:1202px;
  left:50%;
  position:absolute;
  text-align:left;
  margin-left:-601px;
}

#profile_schedule {
  position:absolute;
  top:2060px;
  left:220px;
  color:#000;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  z-index:0;
  width:auto;
}

#profile_friends {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  color:#fff;
}

#profile_password_photo_galleries {
  position:absolute;
  top:2600px;
  width:100%;
}

#profile_password_photo_galleries .heading {
  font-size:20px;
}

#profile_schedule .heading {
  color:#ff0084;
  font-size:25px;
  margin:0;
}

#profile_schedule > .profile_section_content .container {
  padding:2px 0;
  display:block;
}

#profile_schedule > .profile_section_content .container .label {
  width:150px;
  color:#d25581;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}

#profile_main_photo,.flagCounter,#username_container,#gender_container,#body_type_container,#ethnicity_container,#cam_score_container,#hair_container,#eyes_container,#weight_container,#age_container,#country_container,#sexual_preference_container,#smoke_container,#drink_container,#occupation_container,#school_container,#favorite_food_container,#pets_container,#automobile_container,#tags_container,#profile_about_me .label,#profile_about_me > .heading {
  display:none;
}

#profile_main_about_holder {
  display:block;
}

#profile_photo_galleries {
  position:absolute;
  top:2900px;
  width:100%;
}

#profile_friends {
  position:absolute;
  left:220px;
  top:2300px;
  color:#fff;
  width:1000px;
  font-size:12px;
}

#profile .profile_row:first-child {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  left:412px;
  top:420px;
  color:#000!important;
  width:400px;
}

#profile .profile_row:first-child a:link,#profile .profile_row:first-child a:active,#profile .profile_row:first-child a:visited,#profile .profile_row:first-child a:hover {
  color:#f99dde;
}

#profile_interests_content {
  display:none;
}

#profile_comments {
  position:absolute;
  top:2950px;
  width:auto;
  width:100%;
}

.wall_post {
  background:RGBa(0,0,0,0.8);
  padding:10px;
  margin:0 0 20px;
}

#photo_gallery_previews {
}

#header_bar {
  display:none;
}

#footer_bar {
  display:none;
}

a.button {
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
}

a.button.amazon-link {
  width:250px;
  height:87px;
  background:url(https://googledrive.com/host/0B6ETuSl1xvFHZVY1TGlFb0dlLVE/amazon.png);
  top:750px;
  left:620px;
}

a.button.twitter-link {
  width:250px;
  height:87px;
  background:url(https://googledrive.com/host/0B6ETuSl1xvFHZVY1TGlFb0dlLVE/twitter.png);
  top:750px;
  left:50px;
}

a.button.offtip-link {
  width:250px;
  height:89px;
  background:url(https://googledrive.com/host/0B6ETuSl1xvFHZVY1TGlFb0dlLVE/offtip.png);
  top:750px;
  left:340px;
}

/* Gallery */
.photo_gallery_preview {
  color:#fff;
  width:160px;
}

.photo_gallery_preview > a {
  -webkit-transition:all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition:all .5s ease;
  -o-transition:all .5s ease;
  transition:all .5s ease;
}

.photo_gallery_preview > a:hover {
  opacity:.7;
  -moz-transform:rotate(-10deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-10deg);
}

.photo_gallery_preview .photo_gallery_count {
  font-size:14px;
}

.photo_gallery_preview a,.photo_gallery_preview a:link,.photo_gallery_preview a:active,.photo_gallery_preview a:hover,.photo_gallery_preview a:visited {
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

#buttons.resize {
  width:10%;
/* you can use % */
  height:auto;
}

/* Nav and target */
#about_me_target {
  position:absolute;
  top:1000px;
}

ul.nav-profile {
  background:#000000;
  padding:20px;
  -webkit-border-radius:30px;
  -moz-webkit-border-radius:20px;
  -ms-webkit-border-radius:20px;
  -o-webkit-border-radius:20px;
  webkit-border-radius:20px;
  position:absolute;
  top:630px;
  left:480px;
  width:660px;
  opacity:.8;
  filter:alpha(opacity=80);
}

ul.nav-profile li {
  float:left;
  margin-right:35px;
  list-style:none;
}

ul.nav-profile li a,ul.nav-profile li a:link,ul.nav-profile li a:visited,ul.nav-profile li a:active,ul.nav-profile li a:hover {
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:22px;
  -webkit-transition:all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition:all .5s ease;
  -o-transition:all .5s ease;
  transition:all .5s ease;
  text-decoration:none;
}

ul.nav-profile li a:hover {
  color:#8B008B;
}

.frame {
  width:920px;
  height:540px;
  overflow:auto;
  background:#e5e5e5;
  position:relative;
}

.frame-border {
  width:920px;
  height:540px;
  background:#e5e5e5;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:20px;
  -moz-border-radius:12px;
  -webkit-border-radius:20px;
  -o-border-radius:12px;
  margin:0 125px;
}

.firstvid {
  margin-right:20px;
}

div.hover_icon_container {
  width:430px;
  height:107px;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

div.hover_icon_container a.hover_icon {
  display:none;
  width:430px;
  height:107px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

div.hover_icon_container:hover a.hover_icon {
  display:block;
}

.frame::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  width:12px;
  height:12px;
}

.frame::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius:8px;
  border:2px solid white;
  background-color:#C71585;
}

div.gif1 {
  position:absolute;
  left:140px;
  top:472px;
}

div.gif2 {
  position:absolute;
  left:310px;
  top:472px;
}

div.gif3 {
  position:absolute;
  left:480px;
  top:472px;
}

div.gif4 {
  position:absolute;
  left:650px;
  top:472px;
}

#blackBar {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
  background-color:black;
}

@-webkit-keyframes buzz-out {
  10% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    transform:translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  }

  20% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    transform:translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  }

  30% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    transform:translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    transform:translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
    transform:translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
  }

  60% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
    transform:translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }

  70% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
    transform:translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
    transform:translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }

  90% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(1px) rotate(0);
    transform:translateX(1px) rotate(0);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-1px) rotate(0);
    transform:translateX(-1px) rotate(0);
  }
}

@keyframes buzz-out {
  10% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    -ms-transform:translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    transform:translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  }

  20% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    -ms-transform:translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    transform:translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  }

  30% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    -ms-transform:translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
    transform:translateX(3px) rotate(2deg);
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    -ms-transform:translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
    transform:translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
    -ms-transform:translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
    transform:translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
  }

  60% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
    -ms-transform:translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
    transform:translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }

  70% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
    -ms-transform:translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
    transform:translateX(2px) rotate(1deg);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
    -ms-transform:translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
    transform:translateX(-2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }

  90% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(1px) rotate(0);
    -ms-transform:translateX(1px) rotate(0);
    transform:translateX(1px) rotate(0);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-1px) rotate(0);
    -ms-transform:translateX(-1px) rotate(0);
    transform:translateX(-1px) rotate(0);
  }
}

.button {
  display:inline-block;
  -webkit-transform:translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform:translateZ(0);
  transform:translateZ(0);
  box-shadow:0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.button:hover {
  -webkit-animation-name:buzz-out;
  animation-name:buzz-out;
  -webkit-animation-duration:.75s;
  animation-duration:.75s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
  animation-timing-function:linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
  animation-iteration-count:1;
}

.framen {
  width:600px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
  background:#000;
  border-radius:20px;
  position:relative;
  margin:70px 20px 0;
  padding:10px;
}

.frame-bordern {
  width:920px;
  height:300px;
  background:url(https://googledrive.com/host/0B6ETuSl1xvFHZVY1TGlFb0dlLVE/about.png);
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:20px;
  -moz-border-radius:12px;
  -webkit-border-radius:20px;
  -o-border-radius:12px;
  margin:0 125px;
}

.framen::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  width:12px;
  height:12px;
}

.framen::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius:8px;
  background-color:#C71585;
}

#profile_schedule {
  display:none;
}

#new_comment {
  display:none;
}

a.button.insta-link {
  width:250px;
  height:85px;
  background:url(https://5a2e1bf9a2ce6e1087dbd9512e595cd127bfe686.googledrive.com/host/0B6ETuSl1xvFHZVY1TGlFb0dlLVE/instagram.png);
  top:750px;
  left:900px;
}

.design a {
  text-decoration:none;
}

.design h1 {
  font-size:14px;
  font-family:"Franklin Gothic Medium","Franklin Gothic","ITC Franklin Gothic",Arial,sans-serif;
}
```